# Really Broken MySql Setup

Tags: 11.10, server, mysql

I have been having trouble with my MySql setup. This morning it was a working mysql server I added a database and some data with phpMyAdmin then things started to go wrong.

I became unable to connect getting ERROR 2002 unable to connect to socket.

I have completley unistalled mysql server (as best I can) and deleted database files. And now I cannot reinstall it. I get a dpkg error "post-instalation script returned error exit status 1".

Running dpkg-reconfigure reports that "mysql-server-5.1 is broken or not fully installed" how do I find out what it is looking for?

The only thing I have removed is the mysql-server packages, I did install vsftpd at some point shortly before MySql stopped woking, is this known to break MySql??

Any thoughts apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what packages of myslq are/is still installed:

sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql*

To completely remove remaining mysql packages do:

sudo dpkg -P mysql*

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at this [site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1763604). it had been critized before ...

Answer (score 0):

To remove broken packages of mysql or similar use following : `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`. Now try to make fresh installation again for mysql.